# Why background color is set to whole document instead of 100px of height of html element?

Tags: html, css

I have set the height of the HTML tag to 100px and the background color to coral but it is applied to the whole document.

By default, the height of the HTML tag is auto and if I set the background color to that HTML tag then it is applied to the whole document which is obvious as the height is auto.

Please help me to understand the height property to HTML tag and body tag.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Please show the relevant `HTML` as well

Comment: Use body instead of html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's what [the specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#root-background) ask for:

> The background of the root element becomes the **canvas background** and its background painting area extends to cover the entire [canvas](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/intro.html#the-canvas).

Note that contrarily to what you thought, when the <html> node has its height set to `auto`, it won't cover the whole canvas either:

```css
html { border: 1px solid red; }
```

Also note that even setting the rule on the <body> would have the same result if the <html> had its own background set to `none`, thanks to [background-propagation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#body-background).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
body {
  background-color: coral;
}
```

Comment: one doubt HTML node is the root element right?

Comment: Yes it is in an HTMLDocument.

Comment: sorry, one more doubt what is the height and width of a canvas? From the above example what i have understand that its height and width is 100vh and 100vw?

Comment: There is [a link](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/intro.html#the-canvas) in my answer. "*The canvas is infinite for each dimension of the space*"

Comment: oh understood!! Thanks to you and stackoverflow.

Answer (score -2):

The whole document is inside the  tag. so when you put the colour to the html tag the colour is applied to the whole document